# Is there a way to view or download Google Hangouts Call History?

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts, google-voice, voip

The [Android Google Hangouts Dialer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer) is very limited when it comes to VoIP call history.  It only shows the last 100 (approx) calls, even though Google keeps a complete history on their servers.  Also, for calls made more than 24 hours in the past, it fails to show the time of day the call was made.

Is there a way to use the [Google Hangouts Web App](https://hangouts.google.com/) (or any other method) to view or download the call history for calls made via the Android Hangouts Dialer app?